# Avoiding redeclaration for transactions in Xquery

Tags: transactions, xquery, marklogic

Given:

```
let $name := '751-1500'    
return xdmp:node-delete(doc(concat('/', $name, '.xml'))//foo);

let $name := '751-1500'
return xdmp:node-delete(doc(concat('/', $name, '.xml'))//bar);

let $name := '751-1500'
return xdmp:node-delete(doc(concat('/', $name, '.xml'))//baz);
```

How can I avoid having to redeclare $name?

Comment: What XQuery processor are you using? Does `$name` actually need to be a variable?

Comment: MarkLogic 6 (XQuery 3). For the purposes of the example, I would like $name to be a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using separate transactions I'm not sure there is a nice way to do this. But you can declare your variable as external. It will still have to be declared multiple times, but you will only have to assign once when called via `xdmp:invoke` (or `xdmp:eval`):

```
declare variable $name as xs:string external ;
xdmp:node-delete(doc(concat('/', $name, '.xml'))//foo);

declare variable $name as xs:string external ;    
xdmp:node-delete(doc(concat('/', $name, '.xml'))//bar);

declare variable $name as xs:string external ;
xdmp:node-delete(doc(concat('/', $name, '.xml'))//baz);
```

Then you can call this module multiple times using `invoke` with different values:

```
xdmp:invoke('delete-nodes.xqy', (xs:QName('name'), '751-1500')),
xdmp:invoke('delete-nodes.xqy', (xs:QName('name'), '751-1501')),
xdmp:invoke('delete-nodes.xqy', (xs:QName('name'), '751-1502'))
```

If you don't want the extra module, you could wrap it all in a function that accepts the `$name` param and uses `xdmp:eval` instead.

Comment: OK thank you. Is there a way to achieve my example in a single transaction?

Comment: Yes, but from the semicolons in your example I assumed you were using multiple transactions. You could use Multistatement Transactions (new in ML6), which will execute multiple transactions and commit them all atomically. Or if you don't get conflicting updates from the sequential `xdmp:node-delete`s, then just declare `$name` once, and leave out the semicolons.

Answer (score 3):

In one transaction, there are simpler ways, but this should work (untested)

```
let $name := '751-1500'     
let $doc := doc(concat('/', $name, '.xml'))
return 
(xdmp:node-delete($doc//foo),
 xdmp:node-delete($doc//bar),
 xdmp:node-delete($doc//baz))
```